# Cannot truely hide the android statusbar working with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, themes, customization, statusbar

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project and I've just found the way to hide the icons from the status bar with this code:

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn);
```

Now i'm trying to hide the blue status bar, and I've tried 2 different ways, both not working:
1) Add this code to the activity.cs:

```
SetStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent);
```

2) Write these lines in all the possible combinations inside the style.xml (in Resources/value):

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Nothing seems to work, What should I do?

Comment: what object you derive your activity from? what device you are testing on? API level?

Comment: actually I've found the way out! i am gonna pulish it

Answer (score 0):

To hide the status bar and put the app fullscreen in your Android Manifest you need to set your application to a created Theme

```
<application android:label="@string/ApplicationName" android:theme="@style/Theme" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"></application>
```

To create a theme for API level before 21 in your Android Resources values folder add a styles.xml file. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

For Android API 21+ create another values folder values-v21 and add a styles.xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Base application theme for API 21+. This theme completely replaces 'Theme' from BOTH res/values/styles.xml on API 21+ devices. -->
  <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.Base">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Also, as far as I'm aware this should work for all Xamarin Forms Android apps API 19+ anything before that I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Navigation try NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

After so many research I got the best way from JoeManke's [answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35983/changing-androids-statusbar-color-statusbarcolor-colorprimarydark#Comment_193876) on xamarin forum.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            // Kill status bar underlay added by FormsAppCompatActivity
            // Must be done before calling FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate()
            var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (statusBarHeightInfo == null)
            {
                statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            }
            statusBarHeightInfo?.SetValue(this, 0);
        }

        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn);
```