# Fully transparent status bar using xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make the status bar completely transparent like in this picture

[image]

but i could only make it like this

[image]

i'm getting that transparent black bar even though i'm changing the opacity of the statusbar.

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar

Comment: What have you tried so far? post your code as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913652/cannot-truely-hide-the-android-statusbar-working-with-xamarin-forms

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your OnCreate Method in Xamarin.Android project before calling this method LoadApplication(new App()) :

````cs
private void TransparentStatusBar()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                // for covering the full screen in android..
                Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);

                // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
                Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

                Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

            }

        }

    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your OnCreate in Xamarin.Android project:

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
```

And add this into your styles.xml in Xamarin.Android project:

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Comment: hey this worked! but the objects in my page invade the status bar, how can I keep the original height intact?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you should go directly to android project in your solution.

Here's what I found: [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve, go to your android project, access your styles and add this to your custom style :

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```